# How do I initialize a custom class like this?

Tags: c#, arrays, operators, overloading

C#: How do I initialize a custom class as shown below?

```
Point3 Last = { 0, 0, 0 };
```

I realize that I can overload the assignment operator '=,' but I want to be able to assign things like this:

```
Point3 p1 = { 3, 4, 5 };
Point3 p2 = p1;
```

So I'm not really sure if overloading the assignment operator will help that or not.

What I'm looking at it the following:

```
public static Point3 operator =(Point3 P, double[] Vs)
    {
        return new Point3(Vs[0], Vs[1], Vs[2]);
    }
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Create an implicit conversion between Point3 and int[]. You might need to use `Point3 p1 = new[] { 3, 4, 5 }` though.

Comment: Unless `Point3` implements IEnumerable, I don't think you can do what you are asking. You may be able to do something else, like `Point3 Last = new [] { 0, 0, 0 }`, and then an implicit conversion operator from an array.

Comment: Of note, the assignment operator cannot be overloaded, per the article [= Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an implicit operator like this:

```
public class Point3
{
    public static implicit operator Point3(int[] ints)
    {
        return new Point3();
    }
}
```

Which can be invoked using this:

```
Point3 p1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Note that you explicitly need to create the array and can't use the initializer expression. Basically what you do is interpret the right-hand side and provide an implicit conversion between that and your custom type. You can then define how exactly this conversion should be handled.

[Implicit on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)